# Is it possible to know when a label was set/unset to an issue using Github API?

Tags: github, github-api

I'd like to add a new column in a Github issues report with the date when a specific label was added for the first time. Checking at the [Issue Labels API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/labels/) on Github, I see no way of achieving this, as Label entities don't contain dates.

Is there another way to find out when a label was set to an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't currently a way to do this. The nearest thing would be the `updated_at` entry on an issue, but there's no way to guarantee that that update was the result of a label being set on the issue.

GitHub clearly has this information, as the timestamp from a label being applied is available in the web UI—I wonder if you might be better off scraping the page (and asking GitHub to provide this information via the API)?